# Shortcode returning localized HTML part

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, localization

Here's my issue.

I made a shortcode which makes a related article section in post content.

Here's the content of this function:

```
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => 0,
), $atts );
if($a['id'] === 0){
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
    $posts = query_posts(array(
        'showposts' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'cat' => $category_id,
        'date_query'    => array(
            'column'  => 'post_date',
            'after'   => '- 90 days'
        )
    ));
    $postID = $posts[0]->ID;
}
else {
    $postID = $a['id'];
}
$post = get_post(intval($postID));
$post_trim = preg_replace('/((\w+\W*){16}(\w+))(.*)/', '${1}', $post->post_content);

$excerpt = strip_tags($post_trim).'...';


return '
    <div class="rps-container" >

        <a class="rps-thumb" href="'.get_permalink($postID).'" >'.get_the_post_thumbnail($postID,'thumbnail').'</a>
        <div class="rps-desc">
            <span class="rps-container-title">'.__('You may also like','related-post-shortcode').'</span>
            <a href="'.get_permalink($postID).'" class="rps-title">'.get_the_title( $postID ).'</a>
    <div class="rps-excerpt">'.$excerpt.'</div>

        </div>
    </div>
';
```

Everything is fine but, you can see some string translations in there. `__('You may also like','related-post-shortcode')`. I have a translation input, so I can handle it in a PO/MO file (which is fine and up-to-date).

**The translation works great everywhere but in that part of returned HTML, it doesn't. It keep returning the default string in all languages.**

I guess the language parameter is not sent to that function. But how to do that?

Comment: You probably don't use the same text domain in the shortcode as in other parts of the code.

Comment: I do use the same domain everywhere.

Comment: then you don't initialize it for front end

Comment: Does it get translated when printing in template directly?

Comment: @Sumit Good question : no it doesn't. What do I miss ? FYI, Wordpress output the right lang attribute in `<html>`, which is not the default language for string translation.

Comment: Did you load the text domain which you are passing in your string? [load_plugin_textdomain](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain)
Also check it is just about this string or other strings as well? Sometimes PO file does not contain that specific string :)

Comment: Yes, I use `load_plugin_textdomain`, otherwise I don't know how other translation strings would work. "The translation works great everywhere but in that part of returned HTML, it doesn't."

Answer (score 0):

Using your comments, I found what I was missing. I initialized my textdomain with :

```
add_action('admin_init', 'related_post_shortcode_init');

function related_post_shortcode_init() {
  load_plugin_textdomain('related-post-shortcode', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/i18n' );
}
```

So, the textdomain was ok and ready for back-office translations (`admin_init`), but not for front, as @Mark Kaplun suggested.

I simply added another hook :

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'related_post_shortcode_init');
```